# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Touchpad not working properly on Haier Y11C

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, synaptics

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my Haier Y11C laptop and facing some problems like 2 finger scroll and right click.
I tried this

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

But it completely stopped the keyboard and touch-pad, Settings of touch-pad has very limited options there is no option for 2 finger scroll or right click,, how do I solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.